# PHP explode .txt file by new line and separator |

Tags: php, file-get-contents, explode, separator

I have a **log.txt** file with these kind of datas:

```
2022-08-25 13:16----------817650|xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx|user1|10
2022-08-25 13:16----------817856|xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx|user1|5
```

I would like to compare the last values (10 and 5) from the last two lines, but I got stuck in recognizing the lines.

```
 <?php

    $textCnt  = "./log.txt";
    $contents = file_get_contents($textCnt);
    $arrfields = explode( "|" , $contents);
            
    
    echo $arrfields[3];

    ?>
```

I got this:

```
10 2022-08-25 13:16----------817856
```

instead of

```
10
```

Comment: first thing first :) you are not iterating over the lines

Comment: Rule of thumb: Avoid "read the entire file all at once"-type operations whenever possible. @rob-ruchte's answer is a wonderfully simple solution that illustrates this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a job for [fgetcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

```php
$fh = fopen('log.txt', 'r');

while(($currRow = fgetcsv($fh, null, '|')))
{
    echo $currRow[3].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: It looks good, thank you!
All I have to do somehow is to subtract the values of the first two rows from each other.

Comment: @dataeater store an index in a variable such as `$i` which you increment in each loop. You will then have something that tells you what line you're on!

Comment: @Rylee Yes, that was what I did:

<?php

    $fh = fopen('log.txt', 'r');
    $i = 0;

while(($currRow = fgetcsv($fh, null, '|')))
{
     if($i <= 1){

    echo $currRow[6].PHP_EOL;
       }
    $i++;      
}


    ?>

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistake you can try use preg_match

```
$file = 'log.txt';

$text = file_get_contents($file);
preg_match_all('#\|(\d+)\n?#', $text, $mathches);
```

Result: Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 5 )

Comment: for a big file this approach can lead to performance issues.

Comment: Use str_replace to change \r\n $file = 'log.txt';

    $text = file_get_contents($file);
   
   $text = str_replace("\r\n", "|", $text);
    $arr = explode('|', $text);